# Do I need a Japan transit visa to travel from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1 at Narita?

Tags: transit-visas, japan, new-zealand, finland, nrt

On 12 September at 17:45 I am travelling from Helsinki Vantaa (Finnair AY 73) to Tokyo Narita Terminal 2 and from there to Terminal 1 and then I'm going to Auckland (Air New Zealand NZ 90).

Do I need a Japan transit visa to travel from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1 at Narita? I'm Lithuanian.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: OK. I was in a hurry. I can't find a clear answer to my question. The embassy said to contact the airline, but the airline is not replying because they are busy I need to find answer.

Comment: Are these two separate tickets  or a single booking ? FinnAir is OneWorld and NZ is Star Alliance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you will need a visa.

Currently all visa-free arrangements for Japan are suspended and foreign nationals need to apply for a visa to enter Japan (which will be your case since you need to change terminals at Narita).

Source from ministry of foreign affairs: https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158378/transiting-through-narita-airport) (from 2 years ago) says sterile transit is available for same-day flights at NRT. [This official NRT page](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/connect/inter/) says NRT provides post-security inter-terminal buses, and specifically uses the words "...without collecting your luggage or entering Japan..." OTOH, the Japanese Ministry of Foreign Affairs uses the words "...denied to enter Japan..." I think at this point the answer is not clear.

Comment: Here's a bit more: [TravelDoc](https://www.traveldoc.aero) says "Visa is not required for transit through Japan," and [TimaticWeb](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b) concurs that this transit at Narita is permitted. And I didn't look at covid-19 issues of vaccination, and/or test, and/or quarantine.